# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined (Connecting to Stripe)

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, dependency-properties, sqldatatypes

I am trying to connect my node backend to stripe and create connect account directly to stripe and am getting this error (node:3608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
at createConnectAccount (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\codes\Marketplace\server\controllers\stripe.js:9:45).

Below is my code|

```
import User from "../models/user";
import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET);
export const createConnectAccount = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).exec();
  console.log("USER ==> ", user);
  if (!user.stripe_account_id) {
  const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
    type: "express",
  });
  console.log("ACCOUNT ===>", account);
  user.stripe_account_id = account.id;
  user.save();
}
  };
```

I duely hope i can be assisted with this as soon as possible.

Comment: I recommend logging your `req` object to ensure `user` exists.

Comment: I just did and seems my user doesnt exist. How do i go about this correction? This is what am getting now
POST /api/create-connect-account 500 47.771 ms - -

Answer (score 0):

```
import User from "../models/user";
import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET);
export const createConnectAccount = async (req, res) => {
  try{
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).exec();
  console.log("USER ==> ", user);
  if (!user.stripe_account_id) {
  const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
    type: "express",
  });
  console.log("ACCOUNT ===>", account);
  user.stripe_account_id = account.id;
  user.save();
  }catch(error){console.log(error){
}
  };
```

You have to add try-catch block.

Comment: I used the try-catch block and i can see that my user doesnt exist and am getting post 500 error
POST /api/create-connect-account 500 47.771 ms - -

Comment: Yes, then you have to create the user. Please feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: How do i go about this action of creating the user. A user is logged in already in the application and its connected to the database

Comment: are you guys using the same db? naive question but had to ask

Comment: yeah same database mongo db

Comment: updated question...are you guys using the same db instance? can you login to the db and see the record itself using compass

Comment: Yes its the same instance and i have used compass to verify.

Comment: can you check the req object correctly...see the structure and print req.user._id to verify

Comment: Just did same error

Comment: in the db it reads _id

Comment: updated question, is the req.user._id value same as _id value in the db ? can you also share the api route and controller declaration in the question